# Como evitar spam no wordpress sem gastar nada

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de saber como faço para evitar o monte de spam que chega nos comentários do wordpress, seja através de algum plugin (gratuito de preferência) ou através de configuração do wordpress.

Comment: O akismet resolve muito bem o problema. http://akismet.com/plans/ Ele possui um plano free.

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVAS**

**Através de Plugin:** 
Spam Comments Cleaner: https://wordpress.org/plugins/spam-comments-cleaner/

---

**Através do PhpMyAdmin:**

Você pode fazer isso no PhpMyAdmin com uma consulta:

```
DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved =  '0'
```

---

```
DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved =  '1'
```

---

```
DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 'spam'
```

---

```
DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 'trash'
```

Isto irá apagar todos os comentários aprovados - veja se este é o prefixo wp_ atual da tabela de banco de dados e lembre-se de fazer backup de seu banco de dados em primeiro lugar.

fonte: http://blogtimenow.com/wordpress/mass-delete-comments-wordpress-spam-pending-approved/

Comment: mas esse sql irá apagar os comentários que aprovei. Quero apenas bloquear spam

Comment: EDITEI A RESPOSTA

Comment: @VSHenrique, este é o melhor exemplo.